# delayed_job send email with wrong sender on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer, delayed-job

I working on rails 3.1.3 and use delayed_job 3.0.1

I have found some thing wrong with email with in valid email sender.

First I setting ActionMailer to work with Gmail `(xxx.gmail.com)` and it work fine.

After I deploy on production server for a while.

I have setting new ActionMailer to work with my mail server.

And tested it on development. Then I deploy code to production server. It work fine too.

**BUT sometimes email sent to client by use my old Gmail `(xxx.gmail.com)` as sender. (Sent correctly with no error)**

PS. I use rails_config gem for keep email settings.

I have try to debug that for 2 day with on luck.

- print `Settings.mail_sender` inside rails console on production server many times. it return correctly ("no-reply" )
- restart the delayed_job.
- restart server.
- try to put the sender into log. (it write to log when the sender is not a Gmail).
- check on my project there where not any gmail setting or in database.

There is my code

```rb
# config/settings/production.yml
  mail_sender: '"no-reply" <no-reply@myapp.com>'


# MyMailer.rb

default :from => Settings.mail_sender

def greeting(receiver)                   
  @receiver = receiver
  Delayed::Worker.logger.info "-------In inform client"
  Delayed::Worker.logger.info "========inform client from #{Settings.mail_sender}"

  mail(:to => "#{receiver.full_name} <#{receiver.email}>",
    :subject => "Hello") do |format|                   
      format.html
  end

  Delayed::Worker.logger.info inspect
end


# code I call the delayed_job
  MyMailer.delay.greeting(client) if client.can_receive_email?
```

Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't be a test service picking up on that a mail needs sending in production and "stealing" that event/sending the mail perhaps?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not good at english. What do you mean? Can you explain about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already deploy my apps to new sever (use same data) the problem are gone.

Then I try shut down old server a while, after that I start old server again.

Problem are gone too. It's very confuse look like zombie thread stuck on my old server.

Finally I found real problem the process of delayed_job stuck on my server sry for dump question.